# Separate Array entries into DB

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm looking for some help on a problem I'm having trying to inject values from an array into a MySQL table separately. So, not the whole array in one row but in separate entries.

The form is something like this:

```
    <form <form class="reg" name="main_form" action="form.php" method="post">>
<ul>
    <li>
    <label for="text1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="text1" />text1
    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <label for="text2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="text2" />text2
    </label>
    </li>
    <li>
    <label for="text3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="task[]" value="text3" />text3
    </label>
    </li>
</ul>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

In form.php I have something like this for now whic works to put all the selected boxes into one row within the table:

```
<?php
require 'db/config.php';

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link){
    die('Could not connect due to: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected){
    die('Can\'t use: ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$task = implode (PHP_EOL, $_POST['task']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO completed (task) VALUES ('$task')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

If someone were to come along and select the checkbox on all three (text1, 2 & 3), I'd need that to be entered into the DB as three separate entries and not grouped together as one.

I'm thinking I need to use something like explode() before the form actually feeds them into the DB but I'm not 100% sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just wanted to say as a side note that as Kordi says mysql extension is deprecated, but not only that, it was removed from the most recent php version, so you should avoid using it.

Comment: @vove for the notice that it is completly removed from the recent php version. Added this to my post.

Answer (score 1):

## Your Version fixed

Your fixed version but your api is **deprecated** and your method is **not sql injection save**. **Dont use this approach** use the better approach, I mentioned later in my answer.

Replace this

```
$task = implode (PHP_EOL, $_POST['task']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO completed (task) VALUES ('$task')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

with this

```
<?php
foreach ($_POST['task'] as $task) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO completed (task) VALUES ('$task')";
    if (!mysql_query($sql)){
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
```

## Better Approach

Save Version with newer Api cause mysql_connect is deprecated, and sql injection save. So use the new mysqli api. To prevent SQL Injection you should really prepared statements, will update my answer for that in a minute. **Don't use the other approach**. Cause mysql_connect is not only deprecated it is removed in the recent php version from the api. Thanks @vove for your notice.

```
<?php
require 'db/config.php';

$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO completed (task) VALUES (?)");
if (!$stmt) {
    echo $mysqli->error;
    exit();
}

foreach ($_POST['task'] as $task) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $task);
    $stmt->execute();
}

$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

## Output of both Versions

Had text1 and text2 selected.

```
mysql> select * from completed;
+-------+
| task  |
+-------+
| text1 |
| text2 |
+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 

Yes, I'll change the api but before I start changing too much I just tried replacing what you gave me originally and it only ever enters into SQL the last selected box. IE. If I select check box 1,2 & 4 only 4 will show up in the DB. Not sure why...the code looks good from what I can tell:

Comment: @Rod perhaps just var_dump out the sql to see which sql queries you sent to the server. How does the strucutre of your table look?